# Listing the paths to leaves in a tree

Tags: list, haskell, tree

I'm trying to write a function that finds all of the paths to the leaves in a tree.
For example, given a tree that looks like this:

```
           1
         /  \
        2    5
       / \    \
      3   4    6
```

The output list would be: `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,5,6]]`.

The type signature for this function is:`branches :: Tree a -> [[a]]`. Note that this uses the Tree type defined in the [Data.Tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Tree.html) package, and that although the example tree is binary, the actual tree type is a rose tree.

Comment: have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864771/searching-rose-tree-in-haskell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build the paths by adding new labels to the front of the partial path list, then reversing them for output:

```
listtree tree = map reverse $ traverse [] tree
  where traverse path (Node label []) = [label:path]
        traverse path (Node label xs) = concat $ map (traverse (label:path)) xs
```

The reason to add labels to the front of the list instead of the end is that appending takes O(N) in time and allocated memory, while adding a head takes O(1).  Of course, reversing the list is also O(N), but the reversal is only done once per list...

Consequently, the above "add to head, then reverse if necessary" pattern is a pervasive idiom when working with functional algorithms and datastructures.

---

Edit:  from @luqui's comment, a complementary way to get your paths is to build them from the bottom up:

```
listtree (Node label []) = [[label]]
listtree (Node label xs) = map (label:) $ concat $ map listtree xs
```

This is shorter (and possibly clearer) than my solution, and it has the additional advantage of giving you your paths in the order you want them:  the paths are built starting at the leaves, instead of at the root.

Note (as with the previous solution) the path lists are extended by adding a head to the beginning of the list, rather than appending to the end.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to do.  My own approach was similar, but I completely forgot about concat, so the solution had a variable number of nested lists, and left me scratching my head in confusion.

Comment: Tail recursion is suboptimal here because you have to reverse and it loses sharing. `paths (Node x []) = [[x]]; paths (Node x ts) = map (x:) (concatMap paths ts)` works better with laziness and sharing.  (Further improvements could be made by expressing that a path is never empty using an irrefutable pattern, then you can start to output the first path before even reaching the first leaf)

Comment: @luqui, I like this as a complementary solution (as you mention, building paths from the bottom up gives them to you in the order the questioner wants).  But, what kind of sharing does it enable?  (I will also note that my solution is not actually tail-recursive...)

Comment: @comingstorm, ah yes, I meant using an accumulator, which I associate with tail recursion so I accidentally said that instead.  But I think I am wrong about sharing, actually.  I'm just full of hasty generalizations today. Anyway I hypothesize the direct version should be no worse in performance than the accumulator version, but judging by my accuracy rate I'm probably wrong (or maybe I'm wrong about probably being wrong)

Comment: @luqui, I have added a section with your solution to my answer.

Comment: @luqui, could you elaborate on what you mean by using irrefutable patterns to use the fact that a path is not empty please ?

Comment: @Florian, imagine the tree is very deep, and when we use the result of the function we only care about the first element of the first path.  Obviously it will be the root, but the way it is implemented we will have to force all the way down to the first leaf to yield this information.  It is possible (though subtle) to write `listtree` in a way that yields this information without having to force the input any farther than necessary.  (And this improved laziness will not just apply at the root but at all levels recursively)

Comment: Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/luqui/2023240964ee13720f9f2be24da7abbd

Answer (score 3):

just a simple function:

```
listtree :: [a] -> Tree a -> [[a]]
listtree l (Node a []) = [l++[a]]
listtree l (Node a forest) = concatMap (listtree (l++[a])) forest
```

use a list to record path from root to current node, and append current node's label to the path, then recursively map `listtree` to each subnode.

```
listtree [] (Node 1 [(Node 2 [(Node 3 []), (Node 4 [])]), (Node 5 [(Node 6 [])])]))
```

yield the desired result `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,5,6]]`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple...These are the things that you need to have in mind :-

1. Recursively call the function
2. Within the function the traversal should be in the form of PreOrder ( root, left and then right)
3. Use an array within the recursive function and store the value of every node visited.
4. If the visited node is a leaf ...   node--> left == NULL and node--> right == NULL. Then output the contents of the array.