# Need help folding a tree

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to walk a tree and turn each path into a list. Here is my structure. I've called it `Unigraph` because its a unidirectional graph. Apologies if I'm using incorrect terminology.

```
data Unigraph a = Node a [Unigraph a] deriving (Show)
```

Basically, I'm trying to describe a structure like this:

```
       1
     / | \
    2  3  4
   / \  \
  3   4  4
```

I have the following function:

```
comboGraph :: [a] -> Int -> [Unigraph a]
comboGraph _ 0 = []
comboGraph [] _ = []
comboGraph (x:xs) n =
    buildEdge x xs : (comboGraph xs n)
    where   buildEdge h t = Node h (comboGraph t (n-1))
```

for a given list and integer `n`, I can create a `Unigraph` with `n` depths.

So the above graph can be created by running

```
let ug = head $ comboGraph [1..4] 3
```

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve. I want to convert a given `Unigraph` into a list of paths, i.e. `[[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4], [1,4]]`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
getAllPaths :: Unigraph a -> [[a]]
getAllPaths (Node _ []) = []
getAllPaths (Node a (x:xs)) =
    getAllPaths x ++ getAllPaths' xs
    where   getAllPaths' (y:ys) = getAllPaths y ++ getAllPaths' ys
            getAllPaths' [] = []
```

but this function does not account for the value of the node anywhere! I'm getting stuck here. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing the paths to leaves in a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330899/listing-the-paths-to-leaves-in-a-tree)

Comment: Your `Node a (x:xs)` clause doesn't use `a`. You probably also want `[[]]` as your base case in the other clause... or perhaps `[[a]]` with `a` the value of the `Node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base case you need to return node value

In recursive case - prepend node value to each of children paths

```
getAllPaths :: Unigraph a -> [[a]]
getAllPaths (Node a []) = [[a]]
getAllPaths (Node a children) = map (a:) (concatMap getAllPaths children)
```